# jenkins not executing last shell command

Tags: jenkins

I have a CI project  in jenkins just to run some tests and send a report via email.
Running it from a docker console(or ubuntu) there is no probelm , it runs the test and send the report via email.

But when i try to run the same command on jenkins it never runs the last command in order to send the report via email.

Here is the command

```
python3 -m venv . && . bin/activate && pip3 install -r requirements.txt && pytest testcases/HotelesCI/Desktop/HotelPlaya --html=/home/jenkins/hoteles_playa_desktop.html --reruns 2 --self-contained-html --tb=line -k 'test_errors' ; python3 testcases/HotelesCI/Desktop/HotelPlaya/hotels_report.py
```

Again if i copy and paste into a console there is no probelm
I even try to run the last command in another build shell step , but nothing happens
Am i missing something? there is no output in jenkins for the las command

[image: jenkins output]

Comment: is it `hotel_report.py` ? not executing. can you just run that script on its own ?  to make sure it works first

Answer (score 0):

Solved even i don fully understand why , changing the last concatenation quote from " ; " to " || ", it solves the problem.

As i understand , the first option should run the last command always even on build failure , and my change is telling the system that run it only on failure

Comment: Yes, this also my understanding of [concatenating commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists)